# Is it possible to determine if class has template method of certain signature

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I know that it is possible to determine if class has certain member with SFINAE. But is there a way to determine if class has certain ***template method***? For example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename T>
    int method(std::vector<T> vec);
};
```

I also know that you can detect particular instantiations of member template (i.e. for specified `T`). But I wonder if it possible at all to do so with *arbitrary* `T`?

EDIT:

To be more precise why I need `T` to be *arbitrary* type consider example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename Derived>
    void func(Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived> &&arr)
    {
        // implementation 
    }
};

using Matrix = Eigen::Array<double, -1, -1, Eigen::RowMajor>;

Matrix m1(10, 10);

Foo foo;

foo.func(m1.row(1));
foo.func(m1.col(1));
foo.func(m1.row(2).segment(2, 4));
```

`func` can be called with any of those expressions, but `Derived` inside those calls will be different:

1. Eigen::Block<Eigen::Array<double, -1, -1, 1>, 1, -1, true>
2. Eigen::Block<Eigen::Array<double, -1, -1, 1>, -1, 1, false>
3. Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Array<double, -1, -1, 1>, 1, -1, true>, 1, -1, false>

Comment: Why do you want to know if it is a templated method? Normally you are only interested in a particular instantiation of it, so you can just check if there is a member named `method()` that takes a `std::vector<DesiredType>` as an argument.

Comment: I don't think this is possible: the template function could conditionally disable some instanciations ofthe template function, so what do you expect the result to be, if `int` is allowed as `T`, but not `unsigned int`?

Comment: @G.Sliepen The method in question doesn't have `std::vector<T>` as parameter, but rather `Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>`. This `Derived` type can't really be known for certain, e.g. it can have some expression type (like in expression templates), or just array type.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I don't know if it will help but I've added an edit that can hopefully make things more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't write it more detailed: `func()` is a method that needs to be checked for presence in some class.

Comment: Then can you show how that "some class" needs to check for the presence of the `func()` method?

Comment: So basically I have a template class. Lets call it `Descriptor`. It has bunch of `static constexpr bool` flags that tell whether template arugment has certain members with certain signatures. To achieve this for non-template methods it relies on `std::experimental::is_detected` but it doesn't work for template methods.

Answer (score 3):

In C++20 this may be done with constraints/concepts I reckon.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints
See if something like this works:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept Methodable = requires (T1 x) {
    std::vector<T2> v; x.method<T2>(v);
};
```

I didn't test this out, but this may work just fine.
I don't have a compiler handy on my current device to test something like this out.